# Groovy : Deleting all the XML element where tag value has alphabet or special character

Tags: xml, groovy

I have written a code which is not working as expected. If anyone can tell me what i am doing wrong.

**Input**

```
    
<DLF>
    <DeliveryOrder>
        <COMMETTANT>3260</COMMETTANT>
        <COMPTE/>
        <REFCDEEXTERNE>BIS'ART-17.04.23</REFCDEEXTERNE>
        <ETATCOMMANDE>EXP</ETATCOMMANDE>
        <DATEETATDECOMMANDE>240420230000</DATEETATDECOMMANDE>
    </DeliveryOrder>
    <DeliveryOrder>
        <COMMETTANT>3260</COMMETTANT>
        <COMPTE/>
        <REFCDEEXTERNE>WEB230415_33191</REFCDEEXTERNE>
        <ETATCOMMANDE>EXP</ETATCOMMANDE>
        <DATEETATDECOMMANDE>190420230940</DATEETATDECOMMANDE>
    </DeliveryOrder>
    <DeliveryOrder>
        <COMMETTANT>3260</COMMETTANT>
        <COMPTE/>
        <REFCDEEXTERNE>23041533191</REFCDEEXTERNE>
        <ETATCOMMANDE>EXP</ETATCOMMANDE>
        <DATEETATDECOMMANDE>190420230940</DATEETATDECOMMANDE>
    </DeliveryOrder>

</DLF>
```

Requirement : Remove  all the `Deliveryorder` where `REFCDEEXTERNE` is only number.
Groovy Script

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil;
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder;
import groovy.xml.*;
import org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache;
def Message processData(Message message) {

    def body = message.getBody();

    if (body instanceof InputStreamCache) {
        // Convert InputStreamCache to a String
        body = body.getText();
    }

 /*   def list = new XmlParser().parseText(body)
    def nodeToDel = list.DLF.DeliveryOrder.find { it.REFCDEEXTERNE.text() =~ /[^\d]/ }
    def parent = nodeToDel.parent()
    parent.remove(nodeToDel)
    def valid_data=XmlUtil.serialize(list)
    message.setBody(valid_data);*/
    
    def list = new XmlParser().parseText(body)
    //list.DLF.DeliveryOrder.removeAll { it.REFCDEEXTERNE.text() =~ /[^0-9]/ }
   //list.DLF.DeliveryOrder.removeAll { it.REFCDEEXTERNE.text() =~ /[a-zA-Z]/ };
    list.DLF.DeliveryOrder.removeAll { it.REFCDEEXTERNE.text() =~ /[^0-9]/ };
   
    def validData = XmlUtil.serialize(list);
    message.setBody(validData);
    
    return message;
}
```

Output received after executing the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Root>
  <DLF>
    <DeliveryOrder>
      <COMMETTANT>3260</COMMETTANT>
      <COMPTE/>
      <REFCDEEXTERNE>BIS'ART-17.04.23</REFCDEEXTERNE>
      <ETATCOMMANDE>EXP</ETATCOMMANDE>
      <DATEETATDECOMMANDE>240420230000</DATEETATDECOMMANDE>
    </DeliveryOrder>
    <DeliveryOrder>
      <COMMETTANT>3260</COMMETTANT>
      <COMPTE/>
      <REFCDEEXTERNE>WEB230415_33191</REFCDEEXTERNE>
      <ETATCOMMANDE>EXP</ETATCOMMANDE>
      <DATEETATDECOMMANDE>190420230940</DATEETATDECOMMANDE>
    </DeliveryOrder>
    <DeliveryOrder>
        <COMMETTANT>3260</COMMETTANT>
        <COMPTE/>
        <REFCDEEXTERNE>23041533191</REFCDEEXTERNE>
        <ETATCOMMANDE>EXP</ETATCOMMANDE>
        <DATEETATDECOMMANDE>190420230940</DATEETATDECOMMANDE>
    </DeliveryOrder>

  </DLF>
```

Expected Output

```
<DLF>
    <DeliveryOrder>
        <COMMETTANT>3260</COMMETTANT>
        <COMPTE/>
        <REFCDEEXTERNE>23041533191</REFCDEEXTERNE>
        <ETATCOMMANDE>EXP</ETATCOMMANDE>
        <DATEETATDECOMMANDE>190420230940</DATEETATDECOMMANDE>
    </DeliveryOrder>

  </DLF>
```

According to me the output shouldn't have any `DeliveryOrder` node

Please guide

Comment: "_Remove all the Deliveryorder where REFCDEEXTERNE is only number._"...  Both of those in the example are not _only number_ they both contain punctuation and letters?

Comment: And when you say "_Remove DeliveryOrder_", do you mean remove it, and the empty DLF nodes?  Or leave them?

Comment: @tim_yates : I have updated my input ,output expected and output received . If you can guide.
I want to keep only `DeliveryOrder `where `REFCDEEXTERNE `is only number else remove all  `DeliveryOrder `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need to parse the XML

Then find the nodes to remove

Then for each of them, remove them from their parent

And convert the xml document back to a String

This should do it (comments added to explain each section):

```
import groovy.xml.*

// Parse the XML text
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(body)

// Find all nodes which have REFCDEEXTERNE containing a non-number
xml.DeliveryOrder.findAll {
    def field = it.REFCDEEXTERNE.text()
    def matches = field ==~ /.*[^0-9].*/
    matches
}.each { 
    // And then remove each of them from the document
    xml.remove(it)
}

// Then convert it back to a String
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()
XmlNodePrinter nodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(stringWriter))
nodePrinter.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
nodePrinter.print(xml)
def newBody = stringWriter.toString()

// And print it out
println newBody
```

Comment: Thanks , It worked. But I still dont understand why removeall worked in my development. If you can explain. Thank you.